# How to delete specific file every time the Eclipse Java project is run inside IDE?

Tags: java, eclipse

My Java Eclipse projects creates one file as a result of processing the input data.

Is there a way to configure the Eclipse project Run Configuration to delete this file every time the app is being run ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your application creates these files, then when you deploy it to a live environment, it will produce these files too, right?

You should clean up after yourself in the application. This can be done by attaching a [shutdown hook](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#addShutdownHook%28java.lang.Thread%29):

```
Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread()
{
    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        //do your stuff
    }
});
```